# Jquery set value inside textbox depending on results from dropdown list

Tags: php, jquery

I have a working jquery function that loads all available cities inside a dropdown list depending on the selected province (I am passing the province code to a jquery function to be transmitted to a php script to query the cities under that province code and display it in return). The working codes are:

jquery:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#PROVINCE").change(function() {
                $("#CITY").load("getCity.php?PROVINCE_CODE=" + $("#PROVINCE").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Province:</b> <span class="required">*</span></td><td><SELECT id="PROVINCE" name="PROVINCE">
            <option value="0">-select-</option>
            <?php 
            $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select province_code,province from omni_map_province order by province asc;")or die(mysqli_error());
            if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>=1){
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                    echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[1]</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
            </SELECT></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>City:</b> <span class="required">*</span></td><td><SELECT id="CITY" name="CITY"><option value="0">-select-</option>
            </SELECT></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

PHP (getCity.php)

```
    <?php 
        require_once("../connmysql.php");
        $province_code=$_GET['province_code'];
        $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select city_code,city from omni_map_city where province_code='$province_code' order by city asc;")or die(mysqli_error());
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>=1){
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
                echo "<option value='$row[0]'>$row[1]</option>";
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Now, I want to reuse my code to load postal code to a TEXTBOX depending on the selected City. The codes above when reused are okay. But it requires me to use SELECT tag as input and display it inside as OPTION for the dropdown. I want to use textbox instead because it will always return one result.

Answer (score 0):

make a dummy element and use this code:-

```
$('#CITY').val($('#dummy').load('hi'));
```